# Fontawesome5 icon is not working for pseudo code in Drupal 8

Tags: css, drupal-8, font-awesome-5

I'm trying to use font awesome 5 icon for sub menu with pseudo class(before and after) in drupal 8 but code is not working.
What is the problem and why i am facing this ..
**below is the code**

```js
<script>
window.FontAwesomeConfig = {
    searchPseudoElements: true
  }
  </script>
```

```css
ul li a:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 400;
    content: "\f1ea";
}
```

Comment: Please provide full code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: ul.dropdown-menu li a:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 400;
    content: "\f1ea";
    position: absolute;
    left: 6px;
}

Problem is icon not coming. Just empty boxes

Answer (score 1):

The CSS you've provided works as expected, there is likely a configuration issue, likely the font files (eot, woff, woff2, etc.) cannot be loaded. You should use the developer console and determine if the requests for the fonts are failing.

Here is a working example:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li a:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 400;
    content: "\f1ea";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul>
  <li><a>foo</a></li>
  <li><a>bar</a></li>
  <li><a>baz</a></li>
</ul>
```